# Cannot find symbol on my scanners

Tags: java, find, symbols

Trying to create a program that allows you to input the length/width of a picture frame and a picture and then compares the two to see if one will fit into the other. Simple stuff because I'm new to Java, but I digress - here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pictureFrame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double x = 0;
      double y = 0;
      double u = 0;
      double v = 0;

      xScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      yScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      uScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      vScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the length of the picture");
      x = xScanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter the width of the picture");
      y = yScanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter the length of the frame");
      u = uScanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter the width of the frame");
      v = vScanner.nextDouble();

      if (x = u && y = v)
      {
        System.out.println("The frame fits the picture!");
      }
        else if (x == v && y == u) 
        {
            System.out.println("The frame fits the picture!");
        } 
               else 
              {
                  System.out.println("The frame does not fit the picture");
              }

         }

     }
     }
```

And I'm getting 8 errors, all stating they cannot find symbol for the first character of each of the following lines:

```
  xScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  yScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  uScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  vScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  x = xScanner.nextDouble();
  y = yScanner.nextDouble();
  u = uScanner.nextDouble();
  v = vScanner.nextDouble();
```

Sorry if this question is silly, I did use the search function beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put Scanner in front of the statement, also.. you only need to declare Scanner once:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
x = scan.nextDouble();
y = scan.nextDouble();
//etc..
```